# How to get RSA Public Key and Private Key and get the modulus and exponent in plain text?

Tags: macos, ssh, openssl, cryptography

A requirement needs me to

> "Create or retrieve user’s RSA-OAEP key.  There should be one
>   public/private key pair for each user for a device"

and send it to the server in this form:

```
{"modulus":"qMBRpdYrAy5aMmo31NErUizh5sbweguSmh4wlK6uJEIDl+kwTlROnE34KOFExeTbJSX0WygPi+vWl0yNq7buIMUKpytossAAWut5khO3CQJxTk7G2gnEPNUUXHiExGgNrLzcSLv8YIlfVALhoRWyC67KOL+a+3taNq3h+BHeWhM=","exponent":"AQAB"}
```

I tried the SSH command (ssh-keygen -t rsa) to generate RSA public/private key pair, and it comes out like this:

Public key (have changed the value by a bit for security):

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC4NMwqhswK6Py+N1OlPBn3JelqEdZ8YwSn4j1Kvp5HK+pS/5gcABkx/89buDhhtKvZ8mfSNkhKHU2WuBPIikGAvEKbbbQ8DHKubHa07X1xTgY+qMyxTLaHnaEC6oOi6BixPfo6QAm+SnqxBWuvDPBzGqSS+/p5r7aydLBAlkoZ+DzpBbAHIIK72c+xqCL8oOFz4QqsVMakdKQ+fVdM1e8U2ak4ygHOleqJgcl8+xH7TFJsvUOfsgsMlz2FmNXWhCYUdOKglP8ZUVMuiAW9KEjAFta4xEf3bBGRDYss7mLQF5/RHbpzYeNwQ1RVp8bhTumpQytqJZshUj8DA3oqMFUr xyz@xyz.xyz
```

Private key (have altered the value by a bit for security):

```
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,67A126EE3266B641AF4AC698AA18FE01
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How can I extract the modulus and exponent in the form that server expects from this data?

I want to run it on my Mac right now using stock tools like OpenSSL and SSH, and use POSTMAN to send requests to get the encrypted data, and then decrypt it manually.

This is for a prototype which I will then be shifting to an HTML5 based solution.

Comment: Did you have a look at [RSA: Get exponent and modulus given a public key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116907/rsa-get-exponent-and-modulus-given-a-public-key)? Otherwise shouldn't whatever software requires that format have some information on how to retrieve or generate it?